# A radical proposal on votes and reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

I was trying to explain the current controversy how “welcoming” MO is to a non-mathematician friend.  The current best hypothesis for why MO is either attractive or repellent in general is that it has to do with the reputation system.  As I was offering reasons for why things are structured as they are, it occurred to me that there are different goals that could be separated in the point system.

**Goal 1: Determining good questions and answers.** Here, we vote on the questions and answers, and accept at most one answer. This is a crowd-sourced quality metric. Though one may argue about the details, it seems like basically a great idea.

**Goal 2: Managing user privileges.** When you achieve certain reputation, you get more powers on the site. This allows the editorial work to be distributed among many experts who earn their expert status through their dedication of time and the quality of their mathematical content.

**Goal 3: Quantifying users’ credibility.** This one speaks for itself.

In my opinion, the above goals are listed in decreasing order of importance; Goal 1>Goal 2>Goal 3.  What occurs to me is:

(a) Goals 2 and 3 do not have to be so tightly linked to Goal 1.  Goal 1 is an important local imperative, but good questions and answers can be generated by people who are do not have high rep or even participate much, and they frequently are.

(b) Goal 2 is quantified at a second level with a more coarse system of statuses.  These could be awarded without the publicly viewable reputation points.

(c) It is debatable whether Goal 3 is worthy or not.

**Proposal 1:** Make reputation points a hidden feature that only administrators can see. Couple this with an appropriate adjustment to how user privileges are given and announced.

**Proposal 2:** Allow the possibility of granting user privileges based on verified external credentialing.  For example, having an accredited degree in Mathematics (with tiers for BS,MS,PhD), holding an academic position, certain publishing achievements.  This could turn out to be quite controversial and require significant work, but it could also be a way of making MO more inviting to more people.

Comment: My impression is that the OP's proposal is to keep the reputation points of each user a private information

Comment: It's definitely not the same, but somewhat similar suggestions have been discussed on [meta.se]. For example: [Hide the rep and badge count on a user's info box on answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21458) and other [questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/21458). (One point which might be important is whether you suggest this only for MO or for the whole Stack Exchange network.)

Comment: If you don't want criticism on your maths just write a blog or something

Comment: @why In my opinion, your comment misses the point. I don't see MO as a way of showing my maths off to the world, but as a way of asking and answering questions to aid in research.

Comment: How are hidden points going to let users tell apart good answers from bad answers?

Comment: @why Are you serious? You read the answer and judge it based on its content. Actually the fact that you ask that question indicates a problem on this site-- rep-based bias.

Comment: We can discuss about this. However, in my opinion, the real issue is not the rep-based bias. Once one gets used to the site, it appears clearly that reputation is just a measure of the *involvement* in MO, not of the true mathematical value. Apparently, instead, some (potential) users (mostly graduate students, or at least this is the Twitter evidence) complain about lack of empathy, coldness and patronising attitude of some contributors, especially when some questions are downvoted or closed as "not research level".

Comment: Disclaimer: this is some people *perception*. I am not saying that these claims are true or not, and to what extent.  But, if they are true, we should improve our attitude, whereas, if they are false, we should understand why there is this perception after all.

Comment: How does one exist as a math graduate student without experiencing and learning to live with some amount of condescension?  Expertise is a real thing.

Comment: I guess this really depends on the personality. Some people just don't care, others can be seriously hurt by a condescending remark. For some reason that probably depends on the educational system, I noted that people from USA are most susceptible than europeans on this respect. Of course, this may be just my impression.

Comment: I've seen people complain about answers that sounded too sophisticated wrt the question asked.  However, in those cases, it turned out that the person complaining didn't actually understand the question. I saw a somewhat senior colleague harassed for giving a good but sophisticated answer to a mathoverflow question by people on twitter.  If you walk around thinking people are condescending  to you, everything will appear that way.

Comment: Well, probably there is also some kind of "bubble effect": if you usually  interact just with people  agreeing with you, you will be convinced that you are absolutely right.

Comment: Goals 1, 3 would never have occurred to me, and obviously, if they are indeed real goals, then the reputation system isn't working at all. I always thought it was in place almost exclusively for Goal 4: It's a toy that might make the site more fun and addictive (similar perhaps to a rating on an internet chess site).

Comment: About Proposal 2: I am strongly against making a policy of judging over the user's resumé. Besides the technical and ethical difficulties to do so, I think it would increase an existing bias (a big name sounds much more intimidating than a big rep). Being both a frequent contributor and a frequent editor here, I take the rep into account much more when editing than contributing. On the other hand I'm certainly more intimidated in close-voting or downvoting a post by an identifiable user than one by an anonymous user.

Comment: My point about Proposal 2 is what I said before: reputation is a measure of *involvement* to MO, and it is *involvement* that grants privileges. Personally, I'm against granting privileges to "big names" that nevertheless do not actively contribute   to the community.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I’m really surprised that anyone doesn’t find Goal 1 important.

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me whether you want to hide also *scores* of the posts or only *reputation* of users. (As "goal 1" you mention rating system for questions/answers - I'd guess for that score of an answer is more a bit more visible data point than reputation of the poster.)

Comment: @MonroeEskew: It might be important as a goal, but the site is clearly not working that way. In fact, I suspect there is often negative correlation between the quality of an answer and the number of upvotes it attracts.

Comment: "Once one gets used to the site,", yes, but many people don't even get this far.

Comment: I think hiding people's personal reputation points is a good idea, leaving the votes on the answers visible to some extent. This would range from actual net upvotes visible, to only giving a rough idea. For instance, anything over 25 votes, to pluck a figure from the air, could be marked as ">25". The most extreme would be to hide the **answer** votes, but still be able to sort them by upvote score. Questions are a different matter, and to me it makes less sense to know that one question by Terry Tao on a sexy topic has got 100 upvotes, and another insightful question by new user has only 2.

Comment: These ideas are just thinking out loud, and it's not clear the extent to which they can actually be implemented (if I put my SE Inc-emulating hat on, absolutely none), but still worth discussing. Ideally we have input from people who actually have issue with the system. Else we are just a bunch of armchair sociologists.

Comment: @Harry Gindi "I saw a somewhat senior colleague harassed for giving a good but sophisticated answer". Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: @Joël Alright I found it and e-mailed it to you.  You can be the judge.

Comment: I fail to see what Proposal 2 is intended to achieve. Granting reputation for external credentials only makes sense for Goal 3, which is itself of dubious value. It is completely nonsensical and detrimental with respect to Goal 2: people are given reputation-based administrative privileges not because they are domain experts, but because they have experience with using the site, and are familiar with its less common features. As for Goal 1, this generates reputation rather than use preexisting reputation to judge the value of anything, hence here Proposal 2 is irrelevant.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It seems to me that some of the basic privileges, like the ability to vote and the ability to comment, are designed to keep out spam and vandals, rather than involve serious dedication to using the site.  That’s what proposal 2 is about— treating credentialed people a bit better than you’d treat an anonymous person on the internet.

Comment: I don’t think outsiders should be given the ability to downvote, as this minor weapon already requires some familiarity with customs of the site as to what is downvote-worthy. Upvoting requires only 15 reputation, thus literally any contribution to the site will allow it; I don’t see how that could possibly be a problem. Commenting may be more of a problem. It forces new users that have something substantial to say to post it as an answer rather than a comment, which is a *good* thing as they may be unaware they are supposed to post it as an aswer. However, it often makes users lose the ...

Comment: ... ability to interact on their own posts, which is indeed bad. Though this problem is not limited to experts. But let us say for the sake of argument that users with outside credentials should be given the ability to comment. To implement this, we would need a complicated system where someone (moderators?) would need to verify some user-supplied data confirming their real-life identity, and the fact that they have a degree from a reputable academic institution. I’m sorry, but the complexity of such a setup is quite out of proportion to what it can achieve, not to mention that this will ...

Comment: ... not be any less of a hurdle to the users in question compared to obtaining the currently needed 50 reputation points. If the inability to comment is deemed a real problem, the only sensible solution would be to give this privilege to *everyone*.

Comment: @emil Ok you make a good argument.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong -- but wouldn't it actually solve most of the problem if one would just remove the misleading / controversial term 'reputation', and refer to the points just as 'points' -- and leave everything else as it is?

Answer (score 3):

This is a meta-answer, rather than an answer, but I post it here since there is no meta-meta-mathoverflow. I am not hostile to the proposition per se, but the problem is, why change mathoverflow, if we don't like how it works? Why not create a new, independent, math forum, with a completely different form, spirit, and set of features? The web is still mostly free, and there is no difficulty in creating a new site.

Users cannot leave, in any meaningful way, mathoverflow : one cannot remove one's contributions. Changing mathoverflow means forcing people there to live with the changes, whether they like them or not. Their contribution will take a new sense in the new context, which violates in spirit at least what they agreed to when they posted them.

Isn't it better to be a little less repressive, and a little more creative ?

Cours, Camarade, le vieux monde est derrière toi !

Comment: Obviously, I am not again small technical changes, but big change (analogous to change of constitution, in the political realm) are to be avoided. Each one (like joining the stack exchange network) has been felt as a treason by many, who stopped contributing. In my field, 10 years ago, there were dozens of regular contributors. Now there is just one, David Loeffler.

Comment: "meta" is an idempotent operator.

Comment: " there is no difficulty in creating a new site." [citation needed]

Comment: Technically creating the site, and opening it on the internet, requires a lot of work, but is not, nowadays, difficult. I suppose you mean that attracting people to it to make it live is difficult. In that case, if the site has some feature that distinguish it clearly from MO, I am sure that a letter published in Notices of the AMS and a few other similar publications, promoting the new site and explaining its interest, will attract a lot of users. Speaking for myself, I would certainly (if I am allowed to) go on the site out curiosity, and make it my new home if I like it.

Comment: @Joël I'm willing to bet that any kind of change to the mechanics of the site, no matter how hard technically, is easier than rebuilding the community. Of course one might want to jump ship for unrelated reasons (e.g. for disagreements with SE), but that's a whole other kettle of fish.